# Dependency injection of DB service

Tags: class, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have problem with DI. I have custom class, that should be importing some data to database via service. If I use this service in Blazor component it is working well with @injection.

But I am unable to use it in my custom class. I have tried it like this

```
public class ImportXml
{
    private readonly AccountService _accountService;

    public ImportXml(AccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

     public ImportXml(List<Transaction> transactions, Account account)
    {
        if(account.Transactions==null)
        {
            account.Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        }

        account.Transactions.AddRange(transactions);
    
        _accountService.UpdateAccountsAsync(account);
           
    }
}
```

In startup.cs is service registered like this.

```
services.AddScoped<AccountService>();
```

If I invoke ImportXml _accountService is null.

My current workaround is to just send service as part of parameters. But I would like to have working solution with DI.

```
    public class ImportXml
    {
    public ImportXml(List<Transaction> transactions, Account account, AccountService accountService)
    {
        if(account.Transactions==null)
        {
            account.Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        }
        
        account.Transactions.AddRange(transactions);
                 
        accountService.UpdateAccountsAsync(account);
           
    }
    }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

1. In order for ImportXml to receive the AccountService via DI, then ImportXml also needs to be provided by the DI container.
2. You're using a second **constructor** to try and perform the action, instead of a method.  Constructors should just be used to set the class up, not perform any actions, especially long running actions such as updating the database.  Also, note that a constructor is not async.

**Change your ImportXml class**

```
public class ImportXml
{
    private readonly AccountService _accountService;

    // This it the constructor, so just set the object up
    public ImportXml(AccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    // This is the method to perform the update
    public async Task DoAccountUpdateAsync(
        List<Transaction> transactions, 
        Account account)
    {
        if(account.Transactions==null)
        {
            account.Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        }

        account.Transactions.AddRange(transactions);
    
        await _accountService.UpdateAccountsAsync(account);
    }
}
```

**Register both AccountService and ImportXml**

```
services.AddScoped<AccountService>();
services.AddScoped<ImportXml>();
```

**From client, inject ImportXml, and use that service.**
When ImportXml is injected, it's constructor parameters (AccountService) will automatically be provided by DI and injected into ImportXml.

```
@inject ImportXML ImportXML

<button @onclick=@HandleClick>Perform Account Update</button>

@code {
    List<Transactions> _transactionsForMethod;
    Account _accountForMethod;

    async Task HandleClick()
    {
        await ImportXML.DoAccountUpdateAsync(
            _transactionsForMethod,
            _accoountForMethod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, I will test it.